# What's the maximum size for a second partition for moving Apps to a SD card?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, external-sd, root-access, app2sd, partitions

What's the maximum size for a 2nd. primary partition that can be used for App2SD?

Specs: 32GB microSD + 4.1.2 JB + LG Optimus L5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nope, no limit.

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43667131&postcount=3891) at xda-developers forum